# Problems removing HTTP:// from string (unserialized key)

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace, parse-url

**I have urls that I need to remove either http:// or https:// from the string.**

So example I would like;

```
http://www.google.co.uk to become just www.google.co.uk
https://www.yahoo.com to become just www.yahoo.com
```

The string ($url) is being retrieved from serialized data in mysql database that has been unserialized into keys.

I have tried *preg_replace*, *str_replace*, *parse_url* to strip it from the url

```
preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', $url);

str_replace(array('http://','https://'), '', $url);

$url = parse_url($url);
```

I have searched and tried many methods but it will not be removed and the url stays the same..?

If I set string - str_replace works fine

```
$url = "http://www.google.co.uk"; // www.google.co.uk
```

It is not working from unserialized data it leaves as complete...

```
// $website from unserialized data - $website=$value;

$url = $website;
$url2 = "https://www.yahoo.co.uk";

$url = str_replace(array('http://',"https://"), '', $url);
$url2 = str_replace(array('http://',"https://"), '', $url2);

echo $url; // http://www.google.co.uk
echo $url2; // www.yahoo.co.uk
```

Value of $website

```
var_dump($website);  //  string(33) "http://www.google.co.uk"
```

Comment: The first two work. Make sure you assign the return value to a variable, since it will not be done in place.

Comment: ^^ That. Your examples already work as you seem to want them to.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, your string works, but you need to DO the change

```
$url = "http://www.google.co.uk";
$url2 = "https://www.yahoo.co.uk";

$url = str_replace(array('http://',"https://"), '', $url);
$url2 = str_replace(array('http://',"https://"), '', $url2);

echo $url;
echo $url2;
```

Comment: $url = str_replace(array('http://','https://'), '', $url);
 
 echo $url; // still https://www.yahoo.com - https:// still there

Comment: This works ok if $url set this way but not if from unserialized data? see edit to post

Comment: Well check that $website even contains anything, echo $website

Comment: Yep, it does as per post - $url leaves http:// but $url2 removes

Comment: I'm saying actually check it, or force it into string. Try var_dump($website) and show us what it says

Comment: var_dump($website);  //  string(33) "http://www.google.co.uk"

Comment: Okay, it's not replacing because there is no http: or https: in that..

Comment: I've edited post to show var_dump - it does show http: but string seems longer?